# Transforming Dataframe from days to weeks and aggregating quantity column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is a tricky one and I'm having a difficult time aggregating this data by week. So, starting on 5/26/20, for each week what is the total quantity? That is the desired dataframe. My data has 3 months worth of data points where some 'products' have 0 quantities and this needs to be reflected in the desired df.

Original DF:

```
Product    Date       Qty
   A      5/26/20      4
   A      5/28/20      2
   A      5/31/20      2
   A      6/02/20      1
   A      6/03/20      5
   A      6/05/20      2
   B      5/26/20      1
   B      5/27/20      8
   B      6/02/20      2
   B      6/06/20      10
   B      6/14/20      7
```

Desired DF

```
Product     Week     Qty
  A          1        9
  A          2        7
  A          3        0
  B          1        11
  B          2        10
  B          3        7
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do it with `transform` , then create the new week with subtract

```
s = (df.Date-df.groupby('Product').Date.transform('min')).dt.days//7 + 1
s = df.groupby([df.Product, s]).Qty.sum().unstack(fill_value=0).stack().reset_index()
s
Out[348]: 
  Product  Date   0
0       A     1   8
1       A     2   8
2       A     3   0
3       B     1   9
4       B     2  12
5       B     3   7
```